# SSH equivalent of .profile/.bashrc

Tags: ssh, bash

I am looking for a way to automatically define some aliases inside my session on any server I ssh to. I can't put them in the `.bashrc` files on the server because the user accounts I log in with are shared by other people and besides there are dozens of them and maintaining a script on every machine would be painful. I know I could use `expect` to type the aliases automatically but I was just wondering if OpenSSH has anything built-in that could conceivably be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing it in expect. The other way that I've done it is pretty dirty too, with a script, first scp the profile you want to run, then ssh in, run it and stay connected.

So, place all the profile settings in a local file `.<local username>-<hostname>-init.sh`, and run the script below to log in to the remote host.

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "syntax: $0 <host> [<ssh-option>...]" 1>&2 ; exit 1 ; }
host=$1 ; shift    # use any remaining args as ssh options
initfile=".$USER-`hostname`-init.sh"
scp -q ~/.ssh-init.sh "$host:/var/tmp/$initfile"
ssh -t "$@" $host "bash --rcfile /var/tmp/$initfile"
```

Comment: I like this because it doesn't require any special configuration on the server, nice!

Answer (score 4):

You could put your configuration in `.bashrc` and only let them execute when you log in. To make this possible you could pass an environment variable through ssh.

`.bashrc` modifications

```
# common stuff
if [ -n "$IAMTHEGREATEST" ]; then
  # my personal cool stuff
fi;
# other global stuff
```

`sshd_config` modifications:

```
AcceptEnv ... IAMTHEGREATEST
```

`.ssh/config` modifications (client side):

```
Host ...
  SendEnv IAMTHEGREATEST
```

`.bashrc` modifications (client side):

```
alias ssh='IAMTHEGREATEST="forsure" ssh'
```

(untested, but should do)

Comment: How does that fulfill the objective of setting things up automatically on any server the OP logs into?

Comment: It does not. It solves the "the user accounts I log in with are shared by other people" part of the question

Comment: This is almost exactly what I do, but with one difference - instead of accepting that environment variable from outside, I set it in the SSH key itself.  This means that .ssh/authorized_keys contains lines starting with environment="IAMTHEGREATEST=forsure" ssh-dss ...

Answer (score 3):

From the **ssh(1)** man page, if you create a file **~/.ssh/rc**, it will be executed BEFORE the user's login shell is executed, thereby giving the chance to do 'pre-setup' tasks before logging in... the example given was to mount network shares before logging in.

If you don't want to use individual *~/.ssh/rc* files, you can do the same with **/etc/ssh/sshrc**.   A quick test to check for your particular username or some identifyiing method could restrict others from even noticing this was in place.

*/etc/ssh/sshrc* is ONLY sourced if *~/.ssh/rc* does not exist, so you can effectively achieve two layers of complexity.

Comment: ding ding ding - we have a winner!

Comment: Missed that one! While it looks appealing, this will still require setting up each server individually since its on the server-side right?

Comment: yup, server side, but you'd only have to scp one file over, once.  There's not really an easy way to send a stream of commands to be processed immediately upon login.  {Grin}  Give me a bit though, maybe write something... {not today!}

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are defined and interpreted by the shell.

Unfortunately there's no way for `ssh` to pass them to the remote shell.

You could write an `ssh` wrapper on the client side that sets up a nice environment on the remote side, but it wouldn't be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would store a small script that initialize/define everything you want on a server accessible from everywhere and execute it after login in each server.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to put your script that sets everything up on a webserver that all the other servers can access.

Then each server should just need a small script to do something like:

```
wget http://myserver.com/myawesomescript.sh
chmod +x myawesomescript.sh
./myawesomescript.sh
```

That way you only have to update it in one place.

Answer (score -3):

Look at .ssh/config

Here is a example https://lookherefirst.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/a-simple-ssh-config-file/

Comment: Please provide more details about why you think this will help.

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.